# Hiding console when running an Ocra executable?

Tags: ruby, console, hide, executable, ocra

I have successfully made an executable using Ruby's Ocra gem, however, when I run the executable the console displays along with my program. Is there any way to hide the console on launch?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from ocra readme:

> .rb files will become console applications. .rbw files will become windowed application (without a console window popping up).
>   Alternatively, use the “--console” or “--windows” options.